# Combine select and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Quite often, I find myself manually combining select() and mutate() functions within dplyr. This is usually because I'm tidying up a dataframe, want to create new columns based on the old columns, and only want keep the new columns.

For example, if I had data about heights and widths but only wanted to use them to calculate and keep the area then I would use:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(height = 1:3, width = 10:12)

df %>% 
  mutate(area = height * width) %>% 
  select(area)
```

When there are a lot of variables being created in the mutate step it can be difficult to make sure they're all in the select step. Is there a more elegant way to only keep the variables defined in the mutate step?

One workaround I've been using is the following:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(area = height * width) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-id)
```

This works but is pretty verbose, and the use of summarise() means there's a performance hit:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(

  df %>% 
    mutate(area = height * width) %>% 
    select(area),

  df %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(area = height * width) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-id)
)
```

Output:

```
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  868.822  954.053 1258.328 1147.050 1363.251 4369.544   100  a 
 1897.396 1958.754 2319.545 2247.022 2549.124 4025.050   100   b
```

I'm thinking there's another workaround where you can compare the original dataframe names with the new dataframe names and take the right complement, but maybe there's a better way?

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious in the dplyr documentation, so apologies if this is trivial!

Comment: do you know about `dplyr::transmute`?

Comment: `with(df, data.frame(area = height*width))` is much faster. Or `df %$% data.frame(area = height*width)` if pipes are essential. However, benchmarking on such a tiny data set is not really meaningful.

Comment: @NateDay Ah yes, `dplyr::transmute` is perfect. I had it in my mind that it only dropped variables that were referenced in transmute, but I was mistaken. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to give more visibility to @Nate's comment, `transmute()` is the way to go!! From its description:

```
mutate() adds new variables and preserves existing; transmute() drops existing variables.
```

edit: to give a working example,

```
df %>%
  transmute(area = height * width)
```

is the same as

```
df %>% 
  mutate(area = height * width) %>% 
  select(area)
```

Comment: `transmute` can also `select` variables without mutating at all. That makes it an adequate replacement for the `select` method with the advantage of a mutating option.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own function that combines the two steps:

```
mutate_only = function (.data, ...) {
    names = names(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...)
    .data %>% mutate(...) %>% select(one_of(names))
}
```

This needs some work to function properly with standard evaluation. Unfortunately the dplyr API is currently evolving on that point so I don’t know what the recommendation for this will be in a few weeks’ time. Therefore I’ll just refer to the [relevant documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

Comment: That link may break, considering it doesn't belong to the vignettes in the dev version: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/tree/master/vignettes

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.keep` argument:

```
df <- data.frame(height = 1:3, width = 10:12)

df %>% 
  mutate(area = height * width,
         .keep = "none")

# area
# 1   10
# 2   22
# 3   36
```

More options are: `.keep = c("all", "used", "unused", "none")`.

For full description see:

> Control which columns from .data are retained in the output. Grouping
> columns and columns created by ... are always kept.
>
> - "all" retains all columns from .data. This is the default.
> - "used" retains only the columns used in ... to create new columns.
>   This is useful for checking your work, as it displays inputs and
>   outputs side-by-side.
> - "unused" retains only the columns not used in ... to create new
>   columns. This is useful if you generate new columns, but no longer
>   need the columns used to generate them.
> - "none" doesn't retain any extra columns from .data. Only the grouping
>   variables and columns created by ... are kept.