# How do I write a user defined function in r?

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 columns in a table

Quantity int
Price decimal

And I want to calculate the value of a 3rd column called Total.

In SQL Server's transact-sql I could simply write

```
select Price*Quantity as Total from mytable
```

or I could write a used defined function CalcTotal and then write

```
select calcTotal(quantity,price) as total from mytable
```

How do I write a function in R to add a similar column to a dataframe?

I tried to formulate my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744349/how-do-i-implement-an-if-statement-using-a-vector-in-a-nicely-documented-manner)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375156/combine-select-and-mutate?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R this kind of operation is *vectorized*, meaning that you can create the column `total` just by multiplying the other columns:

```
mytable$total <- mytable$quantity * mytable$price
```

or a little cleaner:

```
mytable$total <- with(mytable, quantity * price)
```

The "tidyverse" way uses `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
mytable <- mytable %>%
    mutate(total = quantity * price)
```

If you want a function:

```
calcTotal <- function(x, y) {
  x * y
}
```

And then you can use *e.g.*

```
mytable <- mytable %>%
  mutate(total = calcTotal(quantity, price))
```

However, be aware that not all functions work "row-wise" in this way, in which case you might use the mapping functions from the `purrr` package. For simple operations, it's probably not worth writing the function.

Comment: Thank you. I asked a question that I think is related to your last paragraph. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745336/how-do-i-write-a-function-in-r-to-do-cacluations-on-a-record